# Excel: Count all CompanyID in Range where Row starts with a specific year

Tags: excel, indexing, count, match, countif

while I regularly made use of the content of this website, this is my first question that could not be answered so far.

So the setting:
I have an excel table with column "AB" that shows the year of a certain event (row), thus a certain year i.e. 1995 can occur multiple times in that column. Furthermore, I have multiple participants per event that are classified by an individual ParticipantID.

I now want to know, how often in a specific year a specific participantID occured.

More specifically, I want to count the number of times, a participantID occurs in a range, where the first column of a row shows a specific year.

I would be really greatful if you could support me finding a solution.

Kind regards,
Fynn

[InputFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGy1U.png)

[TableToInsertCountsForAGivenYearAndParticipant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezWFa.png)

Comment: use COUNTIFS().  would give more specific but hard to do so as you only showed the output and not the input.

Comment: countifs didnt work for me, I changed the name of the two pictures attached, so the InputFormat should give you an impression. Maybe you have a suggestion how countif may work in the case

Comment: try `=SUMPRODUCT(($AB$2:$AB$100 = $A2)*($AC$2:$AP$100 = B$1))` Change the `100`s to the last row in the input data.  but it may slow down the calcs too much.

Comment: Thanks Scott, this code works perfectly fine for me. Do I have to close the threat now or mark it as answered? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I just put it as an answer, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT()

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($AB$2:$AB$100 = $A2)*($AC$2:$AP$100 = B$1))
```

Change the `100`s to the last row in the input data.